# Switch between Window and Full Screen modes without changing remote PC resolution

Tags: citrix

I'm using Citrix Workspace for Linux version 20.9.0.15 on Ubuntu 18.0.4 to connect to a Windows 10 PC. When I switch from Full Screen mode to Window mode, and every time I resize that window on Ubuntu, it updates the apparent resolution of the remote Windows PC, messing my window positions.

I found [this support page for the Citrix client for Windows](https://support.citrix.com/help/receiver/3/win/en/Content/ica-xd-changing-desktop-appearance-v2.html), which describes the behaviour I want:

> #### To display a virtual desktop at its actual size
>
> Viewing a desktop in actual size on your computer reproduces the exact display of the desktop in the Desktop Viewer window. This can be useful when examining content such as detailed graphics. Desktop scaling and the position of icons on the virtual desktop do not change relative to the remote desktop, but if the window is smaller than the remote desktop, you have to use scroll bars to view the entire desktop.
>
> 1. On the toolbar, click Preferences and on the Display tab select Actual size.

But I don't see a "Preferences" button / menu anywhere.

I have tried running `/opt/Citrix/ICAClient/util/configmgr` but there is no "Display" tab. I have also looked for a relevant-sounding config option in `~/.ICAClient` but didn't see anything that sounds like locking the remote PC's resolution.

Comment: You are reading the support page for the Windows client, but you are using the Linux client. Please find the error.

Comment: @paladin Thank you for your comment. Yes, I know that is the Windows client support page, but I couldn't find the equivalent support page for the Linux client, and I assume(?) they have feature parity across platforms. Actually I don't really care if there is a similar Preferences GUI to the Windows client; I'd be happy to know where the underlying config option is, and how to set it to maintain the remote desktop dimensions while in Window mode and resizing the client window.

Comment: Please tell us the version of your Citrix client for Linux.

Comment: @paladin Here you go. (Also added to the question text above.) ```/opt/Citrix/ICAClient$ ./wfica -version
Citrix Workspace for Linux
Version 20.9.0.15
Copyright 1998-2020 Citrix Systems, Inc. All rights reserved.
Copyright (c) 1986-1997 RSA Security, Inc. All rights reserved.```

Comment: At my workplace citrix is locked down by help desk and only they can change resolutions. Have you contacted them?

Comment: This is the Linux documentation -> https://docs.citrix.com/en-us/citrix-workspace-app-for-linux.html - I made a quick view - unfortunately I didn't found a solution to your problem. I suggest you open a support ticket at Citrix or try a newer version of the program.